# Tiling faces not parallel to axis

Tags: texturing

I use standart texture from blender. As long as faces of the cube are parallel to axes, it looks fine, but when not - it's like on the image. How can i make the texture on not parallel faces look similar to parallel ones?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by correctly unwrapping the UVs of the model to fit the geometry:

To start, your shape looks like this:
[image: a]

First, I add a texture coordinate node and a mapping node to my texture (or just select the checker texture and press Control + T to generate it automatically if you have the Node Wrangler addon enabled). You don't actually need the mapping node for this, but it is helpful in many scenarios.

Then, change it so that the UV comes out of the texture coordinate, through the mapping, into the vector input of the checker texture.

Then, using the search feature, select "Smart UV Project" on your object. This will generate UVs to fit your angled edge.

I achieved the following result:

[image]